# Can't select element in DOM with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I created a page that receives a button from another page with jQuery AJAX but when I click on this button nothing happens. Code:

```
$(function () {
    //$("#Menu ul li").click(function () { alert("ok"); });

    $("a").button();

    $("#Menu ul li:nth-child(2)").click(function () {
        $("#ajaxLoader").fadeIn('slow');
        $.ajax({
            url: "CreateDataBase.htm",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#ajaxLoader").fadeOut('slow');
                $("#Sample").html("").append(data).css("textAlign", "center").css("paddingTop","30px") ;
                $("a").button();
            }
        });
    });

    $("#Sample input:submit").click(function () { alert("Ok"); });
});
```

**createdb page:**

```
<a id="CreateDB">Create a Database</a>
```

I am also using jQuery UI. [code in snipt.org](http://snipt.org/ufghj9/Default)

Comment: Does the button exist when you do the binding? If not, you'll need to either use the version of on() that delegates (read the documentation), or you'll need to bind the event to the button before you insert it into the DOM.

Comment: what do you mean by *"that recive a button from another page"*? and which click are you referring to? coz there are 3 click handlers here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time your event is bound, the button isn't there.
You want to either bind the event in the ajax-success-callback, or (better) use eventdelegation:

```
$('body').on('click', "#Sample input:submit", function () { alert("Ok"); });
```

see http://api.jquery.com/on/ for details.

Answer (score 1):

Try using live method in jQuery API. Some thing like following

```
$("#Sample input:submit").live("click", function(){ alert("Ok"); });
```

Comment: live() is deprecated now, so unless he explicitly mentions an old version of jQuery, you should probably go with on().